# WP_remote_post how to add filters to JSON API call

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I am trying to integrate an API into my Wordpress plugin. The following PHP code successfully connects to the API and retrieves a list of Estates (the API is from a real-estate software):

```
$url = 'https://api.whise.eu/v1/estates/list';

$body = array(
    'Filter' => array( 'languageId' => 'nl-BE'),
);

$args = array(
    'headers' => array( 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token),
    'body' => json_decode($body)
);

$response = wp_remote_post($url,$args);
```

As per the documentation (http://api.whise.eu/WebsiteDesigner.html#operation/Estates_GetEstates) it is possible to filter the results, but I haven't been able to get this to work. I don't have much experience with APIs and JSON, so I might be missing something here.

The code above still retrieves the data in English, even though I added the language filter as explained in the docs. When I replace `'body' => json_decode($body)` with `'body' => $body`, I get the following response:

```
{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource."}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Only thing I see missing from your code is the `Content-Type` header. Normally you also need to set it to `application/json` when sending a request with a JSON string as the body. Maybe that's why your language filter isn't working?

Comment: Thank you, I added the Content-type header and the 'error' message disappeared when using just 'body' => $body. However, the language filter still doesn't seem to be working. I'll probably just get in touch with their support.. Thanks :)

Comment: You should be using `'body' => json_decode($body)`, that part of the code is correct.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!

Comment: ... on a second thought, no, don't use that :P You should be using `'body' => json_encode($body)`

Comment: Hah, now it's working!! Awesome, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that this question doesn't go unanswered:

- You need to add the `Content-Type` header and set it to `application/json`. This is so the endpoint can interpret your data as a JSON string.
- You also need to change `'body' => json_decode($body)` to `'body' => json_encode($body)` as you want to convert your `$body` array into a JSON string (see [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) vs [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

This is how your code should look now:

```
$url = 'https://api.whise.eu/v1/estates/list';

$body = array(
    'Filter' => array( 'languageId' => 'nl-BE'),
);

$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => json_encode($body)
);

$response = wp_remote_post($url,$args);
```

Comment: I really appreciate you took the time to write this answer and help me out. Editing my code like this fixed everything: the language filter is working correctly and no more errors or messages. Thank you, and have a great weekend!